# Access User Information List into Subsite

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-information-list

I've a subsite where I wanted to access User Information List.. My main site can do have the access of user infor list using the following url

http://mysite:8080/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx

This opens the user info list for me on main site collection..

Now I've created sub-site "e-service" there User Info is not accessible

http://mysite:8080/e-service/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx

it says page not found.. What features needed to be activated or what I'm missing in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user information list is only at top-level site in a site collection.

Comment: so it cannot be accessed inside subsites?

Comment: Yes, we can only access it from top-level site and only site collection administrators can access.

Comment: ok.. marked as answer and voted up :)